# blank result using ui-route using $stateprovider in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using angularjs with ionic framework.

broken demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azvLRa

From my understanding,

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
  <ion-view name="home">
    <ion-content>
      <h2>Home Page</h2>
      <p>Here is the main route for the app.</p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>
```

above template will render and display in

(ion-nav-view is equivalent to ui-view)

but I gotten blank result? I follow the tutorial here : http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/navigation-and-routing-part-1/

Comment: guys no idea what's wrong here?

Comment: helpsssssssssssssssss